# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy intentado realizar un **filtro** pero no tengo idea como hacerlo, puedo recibir sugerencias, el filtro funciona de la siguiente manera:
Cuando le den **click** a uno de los **tags** en la parte superior se debe poder mostrar el contenido que tenga el **TAG** seleccionado en la parte superior, si uno de los **tags** no tiene el item seleccionado en la parte superior se debe ocultar.
**PD: tengo 2 items, cada item tiene tags y se debe poder filtrar/mostrar de acuerdo a los tags en la parte superior**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.content__item__filter span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active__tag');
    var value = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
    $(".content__item__tag .content__tags").filter(function() {
      $('.content__item__tag').toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content__item__filter span.active__tag {
  background-color: #c6a067;
}
.content__body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.content__item__filter span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #697084;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="content__body">
  <div class="content__item__filter">
    <span>IoT</span>
    <span>Firmware</span>
    <span>RPI</span>
    <span>Blockchain</span>
    <span>GIMP</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Tag 1 -->
  <div class="content__item item content__item__tag">
    <h3 class="content__item__subtitle">Title 1. Lorem ipsum</h3>
    <div class="">
      <div class="tag__date">06 - 2014</div>
      <div class="content__item__description__tag">
        <div class="content__item__image">
          <h4>imagen</h4>
          <!--<img src="">-->
        </div>
        <p class="mt-0">
        Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
       
      </div>
      <div class="content__tags">
        <span>Tags: IoT, Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Tag 1 -->

  <!-- Tag 2 -->
  <div class="content__item item content__item__tag">
    <h3 class="content__item__subtitle">Title 2. Consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <div class="">
      <div class="tag__date">09 - 2015</div>
      <div class="content__item__description__tag">
        <div class="content__item__image">
          <h4>imagen</h4>
          <!--<img src="">-->
        </div>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content__tags">
        <span>Tags: Firmware, Lorem, ipsum, dolor, sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Tag 2 -->
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Creo que todo ese HTML crea un poco de ruido, así que voy a tratar de hacer un escenario más sencillo, como prueba de concepto:

Tenemos elementos que queremos mostrar o no, en este caso serán unos simples div. Hagamos que cada uno tenga un conjunto de etiquetas:

```js
$('.tab-body').each(function () {
  let tags=$(this).data('tags');
  console.log('Encontradas las etiquetas:',tags);
});
```

```css
.tab-body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
.red {  background-color: red;}
.blue {  background-color: blue;}
.green {  background-color: green;}
.black {  background-color: black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-body red" data-tags="color red">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body blue" data-tags="color blue">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body green" data-tags="color green">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body black"data-tags="black">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
```

Por otro lado, podemos tener una lista de etiquetas para seleccionar:

```js
$('.tag').click(function() {
  let elem=$(this);
  elem.toggleClass('active');
  console.log('Click en',elem.text());
});
```

```css
span.tag {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="tag">color</span>
<span class="tag">red</span>
<span class="tag">blue</span>
<span class="tag">green</span>
<span class="tag">black</span>
```

Ahora juntemos todo:

```js
  let etiquetasActivas=[]; //variable global con las etiquetas seleccionadas
  
  $('.tag').click(function() {
    let elem=$(this);
    elem.toggleClass('active');
    let tag=elem.text();
    //Si está selecionada la quitamos, si no está la añadimos
    if (etiquetasActivas.includes(tag)) {
      etiquetasActivas = etiquetasActivas.filter(e=> e !==tag);
    } else {
      etiquetasActivas.push(tag);
    }
    //aplicamos los cambios de estado
    mostrarEtiquetas();
  });
  
  function mostrarEtiquetas() {
    //para cada elemento
    $('.tab-body').each(function() {
      let elem=$(this);
      //... obtenemos sus etiquetas
      let etiquetasElemento=elem.data('tags').split(' ');
      
      //si alguna está activa (o no hay etiquetas activas), se mostrará
      let mostrar= etiquetasActivas.length ==0 || 
          etiquetasActivas.some(etiq => etiquetasElemento.includes(etiq));
      if (mostrar) {
        elem.show();
      } else {
        elem.hide();
      }
    });
  }
```

```css
.tab-body {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  color: white;
}
.red {  background-color: red;}
.blue {  background-color: blue;}
.green {  background-color: green;}
.black {  background-color: black;}

span.tag {
  border: 1px solid lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.active {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="tag">color</span>
  <span class="tag">red</span>
  <span class="tag">blue</span>
  <span class="tag">green</span>
  <span class="tag">black</span>
</div>
<div class="tab-body red" data-tags="color red">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body blue" data-tags="color blue">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body green" data-tags="color green">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
<div class="tab-body black" data-tags="black">Lorem ipsum ...</div>
```

En resumen, lo interesante aquí es tener un modelo *separado* de la vista: tenemos una lista de etiquetas activas que crece o decrece, y a cada cambio se actualizan los elementos visibles comprobando sus etiquetas relacionadas. Con el uso de los atributos `data-*` es sencillo tener datos asociados a un elemento del DOM.

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha ayudado mucho para adquirir nuevos conocimientos, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 5):

Lo que se me ocurrió para resolver el problema es guardar en un `array` los valores de los filtros que se encuentran activos, luego recorrer esos valores y usar el selector de contenido de **jQuery** con cada valor:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var arrayBusqueda = [];

  $('.content__item__filter span').on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('active__tag');
    var value = $(this).text();
    
    if($(this).hasClass('active__tag')){
      arrayBusqueda.push(value);
    }else{
      arrayBusqueda = arrayBusqueda.filter(function(elemento){
        return elemento != value;
      });
    }
    
    $(".content__item__tag").css('display', 'none');
    $.each(arrayBusqueda, function(index, dato){
      $(".content__tags:contains('"+ dato +"')").closest('.content__item__tag').toggle();
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.content__item__filter span.active__tag {
  background-color: #c6a067;
}
.content__body {
  padding: 20px;
}
.content__item__filter span {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: #697084;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="content__body">
  <div class="content__item__filter">
    <span>IoT</span>
    <span>Firmware</span>
    <span>RPI</span>
    <span>Blockchain</span>
    <span>GIMP</span>
  </div>

  <!-- Tag 1 -->
  <div class="content__item item content__item__tag">
    <h3 class="content__item__subtitle">Title 1. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <div class="">
      <div class="tag__date">06 - 2014</div>
      <div class="content__item__description__tag">
        <div class="content__item__image">
          <h4>imagen</h4>
          <!--<img src="">-->
        </div>
        <p class="mt-0">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content__tags">
        <span>Tags: IoT,Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Tag 1 -->

  <!-- Tag 2 -->
  <div class="content__item item content__item__tag">
    <h3 class="content__item__subtitle">Title 2. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</h3>
    <div class="">
      <div class="tag__date">09 - 2015</div>
      <div class="content__item__description__tag">
        <div class="content__item__image">
          <h4>imagen</h4>
          <!--<img src="">-->
        </div>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="content__tags">
        <span>Tags: Firmware,Lorem,ipsum,dolor,sit amet</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End Tag 2 -->
</div>
```

Comment: He editado mi pregunta añadiendo css a la clase activa en cada uno de los items del filtro, tu respuesta aun no funciona para mi, se debe hacer que si selecciono varios items del filtro me muestre los contenidos que tengan esos tags seleccionados.